# Simple property access in C++ not working

Tags: c++

Each of these files should be in the same directory, and can be copied verbatim.  I'm having a very odd property access issue which I don't understand with what I currently know about C++.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "someclass.hpp"

SomeClass d = SomeClass();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    SomeClass c = SomeClass();

    return 0;
}
```

**someclass.hpp**

```
#ifndef someclass_hpp
#define someclass_hpp

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
};

#endif /* someclass_hpp */
```

**someclass.cpp**

```
#include "someclass.hpp"
#include <iostream>

std::string s = "hi";

SomeClass::SomeClass()
{
    std::cout << "\"" + s + "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

**console**

```
$ g++ main.cpp someclass.hpp someclass.cpp 
$ ./a.out
""
"hi"
```

I've taken a fairly large project and removed everything until I'm left with this very simple bug, which I've been staring at for an hour and can't wrap my head around.  Is this a simple problem that I'm not thinking about the right way?  As far as I can tell, the code should output "hi" twice, what makes the context of the initialization of *a* any different from *b*?

I currently have the solution down to "don't init variables outside of methods", but I'm still curious why this occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that both, `std::string s = "hi";` and `SomeClass d =
SomeClass();` are initialized globally and the order of initialization isn't
guaranteed. This can also lead to undefined behavior.

FYI: your example is crashed on the latest Fedora.

---

**UPD** As @davidbak correctly mentioned, my answer is about the order of global initialization in different compilation units.

Comment: Global variable initialization has no order _between compilation units_.  In one compilation unit the order is well defined (textual order).

Comment: @davidbak, you are right. That's what I meant in my answer. BTW I've updated the answer and clarify it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Global variable initialization has no guarantee of order. Since the `std::string s = "hi";` and `SomeClass d = SomeClass();` are both in global scope, when your `SomeClass d` is created, `string s` is not initialized, hence the `""` output. As dshil correctly pointed out, this would result undefined behaviour and should be avoided.

Comment: Global variable initialization has no order _between compilation units_.  In one compilation unit the order is well defined (textual order).